# SQL columns filtered differently

Tags: sql, oracle

It's been a while since I deal with SQL. Let's say I have a table Transaction with the following columns: Company, Year, Value.

I want to create a resultset that sums the total value for each Company, but in one column I want 2015 and in other 2016.

```
Company | Total 2015 | Total 2016 |
```

Sounds pretty basic but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Should I create two queries, one for each year? If so, how can I join both results later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select company, 
       sum(case when year = 2015 then value end) total2015,
       sum(case when year = 2016 then value end) total2016
from Transaction 
group by company
```

Comment: Is this oracle 11g?

Answer (score 1):

This is called conditional aggregation.

```
select 
  company,
  sum(case when year = 2015 then value else 0 end) as sum2015,
  sum(case when year = 2016 then value else 0 end) as sum2016
from transaction
group by company
order by company;
```

Answer (score -1):

If calculation logic is a bit complex, push it to a user defined function.

Hint:

```
SELECT company, f_total(2015) total_2016, f_total(2016) total_2016;
```

Here, you write only one function `f_total()`  that intakes year as parameter.

Comment: This is really bad advice.

Comment: Well, to write an aggregation custom function may be complex, too ;-) Anyway, this function should also get `value` as a parameter of course.